# Verify if workbook is open access vba Error53

Tags: vba, ms-access, excel, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

Hi I'm using a code to verify if a workbook is open and if it is I message the user to close the workbook.  This is for an MS ACCESS Form. My current code is as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
Dim Ret
Dim strPath as string
strpath = "C:\myWork.xlsx"
Ret = IsWorkBookOpen(strpath)

If Ret = True Then
    MsgBox "File is open"
Else
    MsgBox "File is Closed"
End If
End Sub

Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)
Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

On Error Resume Next
ff = FreeFile()
Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
Close ff
ErrNo = Err
On Error GoTo 0

Select Case ErrNo
Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
Case Else: Error ErrNo
End Select
End Function
```

I use it in different forms and the Directory changes depending on where the user wants it. It sometimes work but most of the time I get a Run Time Error. When I verify the Err variable it's alaway Err = 53 if its open or not.  Sometimes Err = 70 or Err = 0 and the code runs smoothly but it is never the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error #53 is File Not Found.

This site has code that does exactly what you're trying to do:
http://accessexperts.com/blog/2012/03/06/checking-if-files-are-locked/

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting means "file not found" (you can use `Err.Description` to get something more informative than "53"). Maybe there is a problem with the name, or the path, or some stray characters crept in... Or maybe it has to do with the way you generated the names in the first place. See http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/727403-runtime-error-53-file-not-found.html for a possible scenario and workaround. Without more information about the file name you passed to your routine when it failed it is hard to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem. In my case, I was able to fix the issue when I realized I was sending the IsWorkbookOpen Function just the name of the file, but without the path. When I modified my initial code to send the file an argument in the form of a string that contained both the path and the filename, concatenated together, it worked.